# extracting material from warehouse based on the production plan in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am a beginner in anylogic and I am modeling production process in which there are several different raw materials (defined as agents e.g. metal sheet A, metal sheet B, etc.) they are going through the process and create several types of final products… therefor I have to inject the materials based on production plan and store them in warehouse and then get them out of the warehouse according to the production plan and BOM of the product.

Let’s say that the situation is that Any logic should check the production plan hourly and inject the agents to the model according to that production plan. Here is a part of injection plan according to my monthly production plan. (I have this plan for 1 month and I want to simulate it.)

[image: Plan for injecting materials]

My question is that how can I set this production plan for anylogic to inject the materials to the model.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SOF and AnyLogic. This question is far too broad for SOF, though. For "how do I do X" questions, best use the LinkedIn forum. SOF works best for very specific technical questions. See this for an introduction to the AnyLogic community: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/11/12/an-introduction-to-the-anylogic-community . Then check this to understand SOF and AnyLogic better: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow .  Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good questions. This is typically where I would suggest making use the AnyLogic database and using a Dynamic event to inject the right amount of units at the time specified.

I start by setting up an Excel sheet with the schedule data and importing it into the AnyLogic DB

[image]

[image]

Then you need a Dynamic event with code similar to the one below that will inject the correct amount of units at the right time for the right source.

[image]

And then on the model start-up you call a function that creates all these dynamic events for you from the entries in the DB

[image]

Should be very simple and this approach is very flexible able to handle any schedule and any amount of units

Comment: Thank you jaco-Ben. That worked exactly as I wanted.